# Replace empty record of column with 'foo' on SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm backing up MySql -table to worksheet. 
My current result-set has rows where some of columns are empty.

That's ok, but for the worksheet i need these to be replaced with 'foo'.
HowTo?

All help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Empty or NULL?  There's a big difference there.  If it's NULL, you can use the `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(`MyColumn`, 'foo') As MyColumn FROM `MyTable`
```

If the value is only empty, you need to do something more like this:

```
SELECT IF(char_length(`MyColumn`)>0, `MyColumn`, 'foo') AS MyColumn FROM `MyTable
```

Or you can even combine them:

```
SELECT IF(char_length(COALESCE(`MyColumn`,''))>0,`MyColumn`,'foo') AS MyColumn FROM `MyTable`
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't do it: 

SELECT idR, kyy_FK, COALESCE(team,'tag'), COALESCE(name,'xxxxx'), pojong, krd, COALESCE(memo,'foo'), aa 
 FROM rapsa GROUP BY krd, datetime  ORDER BY `rap`.`id`

i get columns named like: COALESCE(team, 'tag') and empty values on them

Comment: Like I said before: Empty is not the same as NULL.  Coalesce requires NULL.  You might try using the char_length() function combined with IF instead.

Comment: sorry, forgot to answer. Empty, not NULL.

Comment: SELECT idR, kyy_FK, IF(char_length(team)=0,'tag',team)...

thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use "IFNULL":

```
SELECT IFNULL(col1,'foo')
FROM mytable
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't do it: 

SELECT idR, kyy_FK, IFNULL(team,'tag'), IFNULL(name,'xxxxx'), pojong, krd, IFNULL(memo,'foo'), aa 
 FROM rapsa GROUP BY krd, datetime  ORDER BY `rap`.`id`

i get columns named like: IFNULL(team, 'tag') and empty values on them

Answer (score 2):

The `COALESCE` statement returns the first non-null parameter that it is passed:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column,'foo')
```

Returns `column` if it isn't null, `'foo'` otherwise.